# Vuejs key in v-for loop with simple array

Tags: vue.js

I want to build a dynamic form with list groups and user can add, remove and reorder them, with transition. But i dont know how to set key for each item inside v-for loop. As document say use object as key is bad idea, or use index as same as not use key at all.
Could anyone show me a good solution for this.

```
<div id="root">     
    <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="div">
        <div class="form-group" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="what key to use">              
            <input type="text" name="name" v-model="item.name">
            <input type="tel" name="tel" v-model="item.tel">
        </div>
    </transition-group>
    <button @click="add_item">Add</button>      
</div>

<script>
     new Vue({
        el: '#root',
        data: {
            items: []               
        },
        methods: {
            add_item: function () {
                this.items.push({
                    name: '',
                    tel: ''
                })
            }
        }           
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The key should be a unique identifier for the items you are iterating over. Usually that is an `id` field on the item or some other field that is unique to that item. If you don't have anything like that, I'd either add a field to your items, combine multiple fields in a way that generates a unique key, or just use the index. It really depends on the use-case.

For your purpose, you probably want to add an index/id to your items to track the original order so that vue can handle the transitions properly when you alter that ordering.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having a simple array and don't have unique id's for each element then you can go with using index of loop as below.

```
 <div class="form-group" v-for="(item, index) in items" key="index">
```

But rather it is always preferred that you add unique index to each of your elements within the array and use that as key as shown below.

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you use the index as a key, you'll get errors when keys are removed.
For example, if it expects the array to have [a,b,c], then you remove b. c now has key of index 1. This makes it think that b was never removed but it believes that c was removed, so it renders the list by getting rid of the DOM elements for item c instead of item b.